# Android app open website

Tags: android, hyperlink, web

How to simply open website link within Android app? 
Android App is empty, it exists only for this function.
I need to be able to catch Android 3.2+

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried `WebView`?

Comment: No, but I will try it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intent to open the page.

Something like this.

```
String webPage= "http://www.google.com";
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(webPage));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout file add:

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

In your java class add:

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);  
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

And in your manifest file add:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Hope it helps! Good Luck!